# Reload TSV File Without Refreshing Page

Tags: d3.js, csv

I've been searching for a day or 2 for an answer to this question, but I haven't found one yet. I've got an external application which is modifying a TSV file (adding data) periodically. I'm using the [Basic Line Chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/3883245) to display the data and it looks really nice:

[image]

Now I want the data to update when the TSV file is updated. I want to be able to set an auto-refresh on the data where it pulls from the tsv file and repopulates the graph **without** refreshing the entire page.

I tried just wrapping up the current code in a function and calling setInterval on that function, but the data remains the same each time (maybe because it's cached?).

Ideally the solution to this would be a function which can be called to Update whenever I'd like (based on a user event, timer, whatever).

Any ideas, links, or suggestions for alternate ways to accomplish the same goal would be much appreciated!

As a bonus question: I understand D3 may not be the right choice for this sort of Psudo-Real-Time data display. Are there other packages which lend themselves to this sort of thing more? The app generating the data is a C# application (in case that ends up mattering).

Edit: As a supplementary explanation, imagine this example but with the data being read from a file: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html

Comment: Could you post some skeleton code to show how you are using `setInterval` and `d3.tsv`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing an Ajax call to fetch the data from the server and you think caching is a problem, you can try busting the cache by setting the `cache` parameter in [jquery's ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to `false` anywhere in your code:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```

From the docs:

> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and
>   GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The
>   parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a
>   POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Comment: I'm using the d3 function shown in the example (d3.tsv(file, callback)). Unfortunately, adding the command you suggested seems to just break the whole page (although I couldn't tell you why...). My server doesn't even show files being requested. Thanks for the thought though!

Comment: Does the browser show the requests being made and being served, possibly from cache? You can attain the same effect as `$ajaxSetup({cache: false})` by appending the timestamp as a query parameter to the `file` in `d3.tsv(file, cb)` on each call. Of course, assuming that a stray query parameter will not adversely affect the result of the query.